# How to open two types of documents in one folder?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I frequently run a macro on folders that contain .doc and .docx files. Currently, my macro is only able to edit one type of file and then I have to change my macro from .doc to .docx (or vice versa) and run again.

How could I get both file types in one go?

The current code.

```vb
'UpdateDocuments 
    
Sub UpdateDocuments()
    Dim file
    Dim path As String
    
    'Path to your folder. 
    'make sure to include the terminating "\"
    ‘Enter path.
    path = "C:\Users\emckenzie\Documents\TEMP PLOT\macro practice\Andria footer change\"
    
    'Change this file extension to the file you are opening
    file = Dir(path & "*.docx")
    Do While file <> ""
        Documents.Open FileName:=path & file
    
        'This is the call to the macro you want to run on each file the folder
        'Enter macro. 
        Call Permit2hundred
        ' Saves the file
        ActiveDocument.Save
        ActiveDocument.Close
        'set file to next in Dir
        file = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `file = Dir(path & "*.doc*")`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

- Use a wildcard like `*` or `?` in this line: `fileExtension = "*.doc?"`
- You can read more about [wildcard characters here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/wildcard-characters-used-in-string-comparisons)

---

Some suggestions on your code:

- Assign variable types when you're defining them
- Indent your code (You can use [www.rubberduckvba.com](http://www.rubberduckvba.com))
- Define your variables close to where you first use them (matter of preference)
- When working with documents, assign them to a document variable and refer to that variable instead of `ActiveDocument`
- Use basic error handling

---

Additional tip:

- When calling this procedure `Permit2hundred` you could pass the `targetDocument` variable like this:

  ```
    'This is the call to the macro you want to run on each file the folder
    'Enter macro.
    Permit2hundred targetDocument

    ' Saves the file
    targetDocument.Save
  ```

And the definition of that procedure could be something like this:

```
Private Sub Permit2hundred(ByVal targetDocument as Document)

    'Do something

End Sub
```

---

**This is the refactored code:**

```
Public Sub UpdateDocuments()

    ' Add basic Error handling
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    'Path to your folder.
    'make sure to include the terminating "\"
    'Enter path.
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "C:\Users\emckenzie\Documents\TEMP PLOT\macro practice\Andria footer change\"
    
    'Change this file extension to the file you are opening
    Dim fileExtension As String
    fileExtension = "*.doc?"
    
    ' Get files in folder
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & fileExtension)
    
    ' Loop through files in folder
    Do While file <> vbNullString
        Dim targetDocument As Document
        Set targetDocument = Documents.Open(fileName:=folderPath & file)
        
        'This is the call to the macro you want to run on each file the folder
        'Enter macro.
        Permit2hundred
        
        ' Saves the file
        targetDocument.Save
        targetDocument.Close
        
        'set file to next in Dir
        file = Dir()
    Loop
    
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Something went wrong. Error: " & Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to display a file picker dialog and then select what I want. I am then able to choose a doc or docx file without having to alter my code. The Filter property determines the file types allowed. Note that this code clears the filter when it ends, otherwise that is the filter Word will use from that point on, even for manually initiated (non-programmatic) requests of File Open.

This example is setup to allow multiple selections. You can change the AllowMultiSelect to False and then the code will run with only one file at a time.

```
Dim i As Integer, selFiles() As String
Dim strFolderPath As String, Sep As String
Sep = Application.PathSeparator
Erase selFiles

    'Windows Office 2019, 2016, 2013, 2010, 2007
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select the files to update"
        .InitialFileName = curDir
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All Word Files", "*.docx; *.docm; *.doc", 1
        If .Show = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ReDim Preserve selFiles(.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
        strFolderPath = Left(.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(.SelectedItems(1), Sep))
        For i = 0 To .SelectedItems.Count - 1
            selFiles(i) = .SelectedItems(i + 1)
        Next
        .Filters.Clear
    End With
```